# Click Event for Label in Am4charts

Tags: amcharts4

Is it possible to add click event for labels as we have for slices in piechart in am4charts? I searched the amcharts docs and couldn't find anything on it.So I was wondering if this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible - attach an event on the labels' [`hit`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#hit_event) event. Assuming you need this on the pie chart slice labels:

```
series.labels.template.events.on('hit', function(ev) {
  alert('clicked on ' + ev.target.dataItem.category + ' with a value of ' + ev.target.dataItem.value);
});
```